# Flash Administration Server vs Flash Media Server

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-media-server

I have Flash Media Server installed, and can see two services :

1. Flash Media Server
2. Flash Media Administration Server

as a result in my Services List at Control Panel. I can understand, Flash Media Server. But what is the 2nd one about, namely : "Flash Media Administration Server ? "

Thnx
V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a tool used to monitor and debug the flash media server.  You can see the log in real time, stop/start/reset your applications,  stop/reset the server,  close/monitor user connections.   - Among other things.   It's very handy when developing FMS applications.

Comment: Are you talking about "fms_adminConsole.swf" ? If not, can you pls guide, where to use it from, as I can't find any other interface for the administrative server. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: THat would be the one,  you can access it via the web here (if you used the standard install options, if not just tweak the path accordingly)  file:///C:/Program%20Files/Adobe/Flash%20Media%20Server%204.5/webroot/fms_adminConsole.htm